# Microsoft Exchange Server support in my iOS app

Tags: ios, exchange-server

I want to read calendar events in my app from on-premise Exchange server. For exchange online, Office 365, I could use Microsoft's SDK for iOS. I want to know

1. Is there any SDK from Microsoft to support on-prem exchange server in iOS app
2. Is there any extension/plug in that enables my app to read calendar events from exchange server
3. Is there framework/service offered by Apple that can be used in custom apps to read calendar events?

Any link/info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To the one who downvoted the question -> I have explored about this. It will be great you mention what approach is better or give any related info.

Comment: I personally would NEVER EVER enter my exchange password in a strange app which can access my mailbox. Why didn´t you use the calendar permissions share section in iOS like all the other apps? Why did you need direct access to the exchange environment? It might have some limitations (e.g. not all elements are synced only the current one), but I think this might be the better option for your App.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will take a look.

Answer (score 1):

As written in the comment. I personally would never ever enter my Exchange password in a strange app, which then access my Exchange mailbox (which also would explain the downvote). The app would then be able to write emails, read all emails ... means access everything in my mailbox.

So I think the best way to access the calendar in your app would be that your app [access the user’s Calendar database using the EKEventStore class](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingEvents.html). However this has some limitations so normally not the whole calendar is visible here and most users sync only a subset. But for most apps this might be enough.

Via this approach your app also becomes more "universal" and can also work with WebDAV/[CalDav](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/caldav/v2/guide) calendars (e.g. Shared Calendars like google calendar).

Additional via that way you do not need to deal with:

1. bad network connections
2. Different authentication methods (e.g. two factor authentication)
3. SSL encryption (cipher vs. protocols vs. ...)

Comment: I am developing a calendar application which shows events from Google, Office 365 and on-premise exchange server. I found out Google and Office 365 SDKs while connecting to Exchange server wasn't clear